# How can I manage a user token between two APIs and make the requests valid?

Tags: node.js, loopback

I have an API that manages the user's account (signin/signup). 
And I have another API that offers other services but does not handle users yet.
I would like to integrate the same signin/signup for these two API's.
As would a microservice. What is the correct way to do it?

Both API's are made using Loopback 3

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you need authorization of the same token between two loopback microservices, one handling users the other not.

On the other service create a custom User model and AccessToken and override the AccessToken findForRequest and validation methods to query your auth service via rest or grpc.

Reference: http://loopbackloops.blogspot.com/2015/07/customized-user-and-accesstoken-model.html

Comment: So, how I can handle authentication and authorization from 'auth microservice' to anothers?